# screenshot tool for extremely long pages firefox and chrome

Tags: windows-7, chrome, firefox, screenshot

Is there a screenshot tool that works without bugs for extremely long pages with firefox and chrome. Preferably external (software) or internal (add-on) ?

I haven't found yet an add-on that works.

I use windows 7.

Comment: The Firefox built in screenshot tool doesn't suit? It has the "Save full page" function.

Comment: I use Firefox's built in developer tools. Go to the head of the page and right click save as screenshot. You just need to make sure to select the correct structure in the dom tree.

Answer (score 1):

My favo(u)rite screen capture tool is [FastStone capture](https://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm).

Among many other excellent features, I have often used it's auto-scroll feature to capture an entire browser page, no matter how long it was.

The current version costs $19.99, but you can download the last free version from http://whatsonmypc.net/2009/05/14/faststone/  Chances are that you don't need the features in the newer version

Answer (score 1):

[SnagIt](https://www.techsmith.de/snagit.html) is more expensive than other answers here (~50€), but also offers auto-scroll, in both axis if necessary. I have used it, for example, to screenshot the output of database queries. It can also easily screenshot a whole window, or just window contents, so it's easy to get a good image without having to manually crop much afterwards.